# When using SendKeys.SendWait in backgroundworker why I can hear ever 3 seconds kind of beep?

Tags: c#, winforms

Like the form1 maybe not in focus when it's doing the SendKeys ?

The main goal in the end will be to simulate key press combination Ctrl+S when a specific process window is in the front in a focus.

The problem is when the process window is in the front now and I'm using it's menu there are beeps each time the timer send keys like the Form1 or the process I'm using it's menu are not in focus. Not sure.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Process_Window
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

            worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted; ;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("^s");
        }

        private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't get help with SendKeys code, only you could possibly know what window gets the keystroke.  Well, wrong one when it beeps perhaps.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SetForeGroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow)

You could use this just before calling `SendKeys.SendWait()` so you're quite sure you sent Ctrl+S to the good window, you can use SetForeGroundWindow with FindWindow if i remember the name correctly.